# How to create an inclusive aar file in Android

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-build

How do we create an aar file that includes all its dependent projects in `Android` `gradle` build?

Say I have `ProjectA` that is Android gradle library that depends on another library called `ProjectB` which is in ant build. I would like to build an aar file thats inclusive of 'ProjectB`.

If its not possible across two different build systems.